# Webpack Config: Querying the mode option within plugin creation

Tags: webpack, webpack.config.js, mini-css-extract-plugin

How would I go about querying the `mode` within my `webpack.config.js` configuration file?

Here's what I want to do.  I have the `mode` set in my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
}
```

When I initialize the `mini-css-extract-plugin` I want to check the value of `mode`:

```
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: (mode === 'development' ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
    chunkFilename: (mode === 'development' ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
  })
],
```

Obviously that doesn't work.  How do I query `mode` within that plugin initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that lets me access `mode` as passed as an argument but I'd still like to find a way to access the `mode` property as defined in the config.

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: (argv.mode === 'development') ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: (argv.mode === 'development') ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: you either split different config files for different environments (use webpack-merge), or you do the way you doing right now. Access directly the mode above is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

my idea.

run `NODE_ENV=development webpack` and `NODE_ENV=production webpack` or `webpack`

```
/* -------------------------------------
 *  webpack.config.js
 * ------------------------------------- */
const node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'production';
const devMode = node_env !== 'production';
if (devMode) {
   console.log('Looks like we are in development mode!');
}

module.exports = {
  mode: node_env,
...
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: devMode ? '[name].[hash].css' : '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].[hash].css' : '[id].css',
      }
    })
  ],
...
}
```